# PDEs involving a hilbert transform

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm investigating a nonlinear Schrodinger equation of the form

$$iA_t+A_{xx}+|A|^2A +A\mathbb{H}(|A|^2_x)= 0,$$

where $A=A(x,t)$ is a complex valued function and $\mathbb{H}$ is the Hilbert transform, i.e.

$$\mathbb{H}(|A|^2_x) = \frac{1}{\pi}P.V. \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{|A|^2_{x'}}{x-x'} \ dx'. $$

I'm attempting to make progress in analyzing solutions to this PDE, but the presence of nonlinear term in the Hilbert transform makes things difficult.

Are there general transforms that would make (a heuristic) investigation of possible solutions simpler?